# C# Project & Namespaces Question

Tags: c#, namespaces, project

I am creating a little Math library for myself contained within a single project and am running into some issues with namespaces. I have the project `MyMathLib` and the top level namespace:

```
namespace MyMathLib
{ ... }
```

and in a separate file...

```
namespace MyMathLib.Addition
{ ... }
```

and...

```
namespace MyMathLib.Subtraction
{ ... }
```

In the `MyMathLib.Subtraction` namespace I have a method that needs to use a static method `SomeClass.Work()` defined in `MyMathLib.Addition` so I included `using MyMathLib.Addition` at the beginning of the Subtraction file. But when I try to use the method it would like me to first qualify it with `Addition.SomeClass.Work()` and I want to be able to just type `SomeClass.Work()`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks for the suggestions! In each file, I actually named the class after the namespace (i.e. in the namespace `MyMathLib.Addition` is a static class `Addition` and in `MyMathLib.Subtraction` there is a static class `Subtraction`). Apparently this is what caused the issue (looking back, I should have stated this instead of using `SomeClass`). If I change the namespace to `MyMathLib.MyAddition` while keeping the static class as `Addition`, the `using MyMathLib.MyAddition` works as I want; that is, I can now just type `Addition.Work()` in my static `Subtraction` class. I've seen classes named the same as it's containing namespace before, could someone maybe explain why this is causing an issue? Shouldn't the compiler be able to determine whether I want to use the namespace or the class from the context of the code?

Comment: Does the method name conflict with another method in another namespace you reference?

Comment: Perhaps you use the same name for SomeClass and Work() in both namespaces?

Comment: Is `Work` a member of `SomeClass`? Furthermore, is `SomeClass` defined in both `MyMathLib.Addition` and `MyMathLib.Subtraction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you either have two classes called `SomeClass` that are both in namespaces you reference, or you have a variable or property named `SomeClass`. Either of these situations would make it impossible for the compiler to know that you're trying to call the static `MyMathLib.Addition.SomeClass.Work()` method, but the specific solution the compiler is suggesting makes it seem more likely to be the former.

#### Update

Seeing your edit, that makes sense. If you were using these in a namespace outside of `MyMathLib`, then you would still be able to avoid this namespace conflict. However, because you are inside the `MyMathLib.Subtraction` namespace, the compiler will implicitly consider any portion of the namespace "above" you to take precedence over class names. In this case, when you say "Addition", the compiler will look for the following items to resolve the name:

1. A class explicitly identified by a `using ... = ...` directive.
2. `MyMathLib.Subtraction.Addition` namespace.
3. `MyMathLib.Addition` namespace.
4. `Addition` namespace.
5. Any classes in the namespaces identified by `using` statements.

In this case, you're hitting #3 before #4, so you should be able to work around it either by renaming the class or namespace, or by using Yahia's suggestion (#1):

```
using Addition = MyMathLib.Addition.Addition;
```

#### Update 2

After looking at the article you linked to, it sounds like the explicit `using` statement still won't work. I guess item #1 actually gets evaluated down around item #4 instead. Bummer. You can use an alias to give the class a *different* name locally:

```
using Add = MyMathLib.Addition.Addition;

...

var add = new Add();
```

But the best solution is still probably just to avoid the namespace collision entirely by changing your namespace or class name.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I found a "solution" but I'm not really sure why it works (see my edit above).

Comment: Hmmm... I tried the `using Addition = MyMathLib.Addition.Addition` but IntelliSense still reverts right to the Addition namespace and not the class. Thoughts?

Comment: Well I just found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx) on the topic. Looks like I will be changing the naming of my namespace. :)

Comment: @Jon: Yes, that's probably the best approach. I'm sure that's why `System.Linq.Expressions` has an `s` on the end (to avoid collision with the `Expression` class.

Answer (score 1):

try putting additionally the floowing line into your substraction source

```
using SomeClass = Addition.SomeClass;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NamespaceAliasQualifier.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're in the Subtraction namespace...add this to the top, inside the namespace declaration:

```
using Addition;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: That will most likely not work, because (a) the namespace is called `MyMathLib.Addition`, not just `Addition`; and (b) the OP has already done that.

Comment: I mocked it up in Visual Studio and it worked. When there is a match on a portion of a namespace, you need only specify the child portion of the namespace which doesn't match. Please check it out yourself and remove my -1.